# Why console.trace() result end at an "anonymous function"? What is that function?

Tags: javascript, function, stack-trace, console.log

If I run the code in the Javascript Console of an browser such as Chrome:

```
function foo() {
  function bar() {
    console.trace();
   }
   bar();
}
foo();
```

The result will be:

```
bar
foo
(anonymous function)
```

The `console.trace()` may trace to 'global scope' at the end. I know the global in the browser is the `window` object. But what is the specific function that `(anonymous function)` points to in the result?

Comment: Probably the wrapper function that the console puts your code into to run it, similar to `new Function('', 'user input here')()`

Comment: There will be link in your console next to every method , click on that  , In your case anonymous point to foo() itself

Comment: He mentioned that he is executing in browser console

Comment: You can use a `debugger;` statement to inspect the stack dynamically. Click on that dubious function and it'll show you its source.

Answer (score 1):

Its expecting an `anonymous` function as `argument`.

```
function Vinoth(){console.log("Vinoth")}
undefined

console.trace(Vinoth());
VM129:1 Vinoth
```

More info on this link: 
https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/blob/master/api.md#consoletraceobject--object-